# Removing line breaks in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a problem removing `\n` and `\r` tags. When I'm using double quotes, it works fine, otherwise it leaves `"\"`. With `gsub`, it doesn't work without double quotes at all. Why?

```
"Remove \n".delete('\n') # result: "Remove" 
'Remove \n'.delete('\n') # result: "Remove \"
```

I found this because it doesn't work with results from the database.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Single-quoted strings do not process most escape sequences. So, when you have this

```
'\n'
```

it literally means "two character string, where first character is backslash and second character is lower-case 'n'". It does **not** mean "newline character". In order for `\n` to mean newline char, you have to put it inside of double-quoted string (which does process this escape sequence). Here are a few examples:

```
"Remove \n".delete('\n') # => "Remove \n" # doesn't match
'Remove \n'.delete('\n') # => "Remove \\" # see below

'Remove \n'.delete("\n") # => "Remove \\n" # no newline in source string
"Remove \n".delete("\n") # => "Remove " # properly removed
```

**NOTE** that backslash character in this particular example (second line, using single-quoted string in `delete` call) is simply ignored, because of special logic in the `delete` method. See doc on [String#count](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-count) for more info. To bypass this, use `gsub`, for example

```
'Remove \n'.gsub('\n', '') # => "Remove "
```

Comment: Thanks Sergio. Maybe you know how can I convert results received from database, because I think they are tracted as in single quotes

Comment: Maybe I do know. But that's out of scope here :)

Answer (score 2):

From [Ruby Programming/Strings](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Strings#Single_quotes)

> Single quotes only support two escape sequences.
>
> ```
> \' – single quote
> \\ – single backslash
> ```
>
> Except for these two escape sequences, everything else between single quotes is treated literally.

So if you type `\n` in the irb, you get back `\\n`.

This is why you have problems with `delete`

```
"Remove \n".delete('\n') #=> "Remove \n".delete("\\n") => "Remove \n"
'Remove \n'.delete('\n') #=> "Remove \\n".delete("\\n") => "Remove \\"
```

Comment: Your second line produces different output for me. Are you sure about it?

Comment: Should be delete("\n")

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about extra blank spaces, the cleanest solution is to use [#strip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/String.html#method-i-strip):

```rb
"Remove \n".strip
```